# Delete/detach first pivot table records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.3

**Case**
  *Laravel 5.3*

Having a pivot table between `Cart` & `Product` with an additional column:

```
id - cart_id - product_id - item_id (additional column)
1  -    1    -     1      -    5
2  -    1    -     1      -    6
3  -    1    -     1      -    7
4  -    2    -     1      -    8
```

Normally you detach a pivot table record using:
`$product->carts()->detach($cartId);`

But in this case, there are several pivot table records with the same `cart` & `product` `id`

**Problem**

Lets say I want delete to `row 1`.

What I hoped to work was either one of these:
`$product->carts()->detach($itemId);`
or
`$product->carts()->detach($cartId)->first();`

If I query the pivot table based on `cart_id` & `product_id`, call the `first` & run `delete()` on that query result a `Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()` will be returned

```
$firstItem = DB::table('cart_product')
  ->where('cart_id', $cart_id)
  ->where('product_id', $product->id)
  ->first();    

$firstItem->delete();
```

Although when I `dd()` `$firstItem` after querying the data, it will return a (correct) object

```
{#238 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"cart_id": 1
  +"product_id": 1
  +"item_id": 5
}
```

Comment: From my understanding and experience `$product->carts()->detach($itemId);` should work. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @devk look closer. `$itemId` is an ID of additional column, but not `cart_id`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Oh I see. Shouldn't `$product->carts()->where('cart_product.item_id', $itemId)->detach()` work though? Assuming there is `->withPivot(['item_id'])` on the relationship.

Comment: @devk I'm not sure about this, ask Liam to try. ) Also his code doesn't know item ID yet and he needs to get it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `detach()` if you want to delete just one row in this table.

If you want to delete just first item, just use this:

```
DB::table('cart_product')
  ->where('cart_id', $cart_id)
  ->where('product_id', $product->id)
  ->take(1)
  ->delete();
```

Or from your code:

```
$id = DB::table('cart_product')
  ->where('cart_id', $cart_id)
  ->where('product_id', $product->id)
  ->first()->id;

DB::table('cart_product')
  ->where('id', $id)
  ->delete();
```

Comment: That results into a  Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `first()`, `find()` or something else? Because [syntax is correct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#deletes)

Comment: Ok, you've updated your question and you've added `first()` to my code. Remove it, just use code from my answer without modification.

Comment: I don't have $itemId before the call, I get the $itemId after running the query

Comment: Why did you post this code `$product->carts()->detach($itemId);` then? I've updated my code with code you need.

Comment: Because I runned that function after the query on cart_product table, but your latest answer worked like a charm!